# dynamically creating the partition name as sysdate?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-partitioning

How to give the name to the partition dynamically. I have a requirement in which i'm creating the interval partitioning on monthly basis. I want to give '1-jan-2014' , '1-Feb-2014' as partition names? Please suggest the approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problem here because interval partitioning has system generated partition names...
So you have to change this generated names after creation, this problem is resolved here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33225/rename-interval-partitioning-system-generated-partition-names

or here

http://bobjankovsky.org/show.php?seq=90

You could make a job which will periodically change the partition names.

Comment: Hi, Thank for the answers. But my requirement is to give the date as inputs while creating partition itself. IS there a way? rather than creating the stored procedure to rename it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding a partition to an existing table you'd need to do it dynamically. And since you want the name to have dashes in as date element separators the partition names would have to be quoted identifiers, which will make working with them explicitly a bit more complicated later.

If you have a table that initially has named partitions:

```
create table t42 (date_col date, other_col varchar2(10))
partition by range (date_col)
(
  partition "Pre-2014" values less than (date '2014-01-01'),
  partition "1-jan-2014" values less than (date '2014-02-01'),
  partition "1-feb-2014" values less than (date '2014-03-01'),
  partition "1-mar-2014" values less than (date '2014-04-01'),
  partition "1-apr-2014" values less than (date '2014-05-01')
);
```

Then you can manually add a new named partition:

```
alter table t42 add partition "1-may-2014" values less than (date '2014-06-01');
alter table t42 add partition "1-jun-2014" values less than (date '2014-07-01');
```

If you want to add a new partition based on `sysdate` (or any date) then you'd need dynamic SQL to generate that command; here in an anonymous block but you coudl have a procedure if you want to pass a date in:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'alter table t42 add partition "'
    || to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'FMdd-mon-yyyy')
    || '" values less than (date '''
    || to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    || ''')';
end;
/
```

Today that would generate and execute command:

```
alter table t42 add partition "1-jul-2014" values less than (date '2014-08-01')
```

Then you can see the partition is named as you wanted:

```
select partition_name from user_tab_partitions order by partition_position;

PARTITION_NAME               
------------------------------
Pre-2014                       
1-jan-2014                     
1-feb-2014                     
1-mar-2014                     
1-apr-2014                     
1-may-2014                     
1-jun-2014                     
1-jul-2014
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i'm creating the new table and partitions for that. Can we use the dynamic sql in the create table command i mean internally it will create the partition having sysdate as name?

Comment: @Sushma - why would you be creating a table dynamically? I mean yes, you can do it through `execute immediate` in the same way, but normally you'd create the table statically and in a controlled way. I can see a scenario for adding new partitions like this, maybe through a scheduled monthly job, but not for creating a new table?

Comment: Yeah..you are right. Table is created statically once, I want to give the name of the partition as sysdate. Is it possible to give sysdate as partition name while creating the partition it self?

Comment: @Sushma - if you can't just type it then then you can do it in an anonymous block in the same way I have above, just with a `create table` instead of an `alter table`. The partition name has to be a literal value though, you can't use `to_char(sysdate)` for example - hence it needing to be dynamic if you need that.